# Pandas Dataframe - Turn Columns To Rows Sorted by "Grand Totals" Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in a dataframe that looks like this, where each column is a KEYWORD and each row is an observation of how many times each ID said the word:

| id | bagel | pizza |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 | 3 |
| DEF | 1 | 3 |
| GHI | 7 | 9 |
| TOTAL | 10 | 15 |

I am trying to get it to a form where I can see what the most popular word is overall, something where the columns themselves are new columns and the TOTAL row transforms to a column that can be sorted:

| Column | Total |
| --- | --- |
| bagel | 10 |
| pizza | 15 |

I have tried `melt` and `stack` but I dont think I am using either one correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.sum()`

```
data = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
```

The code above will return a series, you need to convert it into a DataFrame using the syntax below and set the column names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column':data.index, 'Total':data.values})
print(df)
```

That gives me,

```
    Column  Total
0   bagel   10
1   pizza   15
```

You can also do the following to set the `Column` column as the index removing the (0, 1, etc.) index.

```
df = df.set_index('Column')
print(df)
```

Which gives me,

```
         Total
Column  
bagel    10
pizza    15
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the column then `T`

```
out = df[df.id.eq('TOTAL')].set_index('id').T.reset_index()
Out[433]: 
id  index  TOTAL
0   bagel     10
1   pizza     15
```